# I get expected constant expression error in VS, but it runs on tutorialspoint web compiler?

Tags: c, syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

const int MAX = 3;

int main() {

    int var[] = { 10, 100, 200 };
    int i, *ptr[MAX];

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) { 
        ptr[i] = &var[i]; /* assign the address of integer. */
        _getch();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i]);
        _getch();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code by indenting everything 4 spaces. All your semi-colons (;) had open-curly-braces after them. "{". I removed them, thinking they were mistakes from your cutting and pasting. Is this the code you're running?  If you get an error message, cut and paste that too, and say what line of code is indicated.

Comment: And by the way welcome to StackOverflow! Including the precise error message in clear text helps others google this solution.

Comment: Thank you! This is not my code and it was my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition `int *ptr[MAX];` where `MAX` is not a compile time constant expression is supported since C99 for automatic variables.  Even defined as a `const int MAX = 3`, `MAX` is not considered a compile time constant in C.  Your version of Visual Studio does not seem to support this syntax, but the online compiler at tutorialspoint does.